# Changed the name of project, missing libPods?

Tags: sdk, frameworks, cocoapods, missing-data

I changed the name of my project in my XCWorkspace, and now my libPods are missing...well at least thats what XCode believes. I tried restoring the snapshot and it did, however the pods are still missing.  I tend to think I didn't do anything too harsh, just followed the tutorial on how to change my projects name and now its broke.  Is there a simple fix to adding these back into my life?  I miss them, and productivity has come to a halt :(

[image: Red Warning]

[image: Red Warning 2]

[image: Red Warning 3]

[image: Red Warning 4]

Comment: I tried reinstalling the pods (pods install in terminal) and unfortunately it wasn't successful.